# Coin Flip Code- Trying to count string out put

Tags: java

So now I edited the code that counts the number of heads in row when there are four AND the number of heads in a row when there are five. I have the following code that runs correctly, but it is only counting the number of fours not the number of fives. Can anyone help me? I copy and pasted the results I get when the trail runs as well after my code.

```
public class Flip {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
      final int FLIPS = 100;
     int heads = 0;
     int consecCountfour = 0;
     int consecCountfive = 0;
   System.out.println("Trail Tosses:");
   for (int i = 1; i<= FLIPS; i++)
    {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) { 
     System.out.print("h"); 
     heads++;
     }
    else {               
       System.out.print("t");
     if (heads == 4) { consecCountfour++; }
     heads = 0;

     if (heads == 5) { consecCountfive++; }
     heads = 0;
     }



  }
  System.out.println("\n");
  System.out.print("Count hhhh:"+ consecCountfour);
 System.out.print("     Count hhhhh:" + consecCountfive);
  }
 }
```

Comment: `int heads=0;` coin comes up as heads: `heads++;`

Comment: You need some variables to count with first

Comment: how could I make the hs and ts countable if that makes sense? what would I have to write to make my results a string to count

Answer (score 0):

A decent solution would be to count the number of consecutive heads which is set back to 0 when tails is flipped.

```
final int FLIPS = 100;
int heads = 0;
int consecCount = 0;
for (int i = 1; i<= FLIPS; i++)
{
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) { 
         System.out.print("h"); 
         heads++;
    }
    else {               
         System.out.print("t");
         if (heads == 4 || heads == 5) { consecCount++; }
         heads = 0;
    }
}
System.out.print(consecCount);
```

Comment: thank you that code complies nicely! how could I print the number of consecutive "hhhh" and "hhhhh" though?

Comment: @Alex sort the h's and t's into two different strings, then use .length() for the value.

Comment: @Alex The variables may be a little misleading, but headCount counts the number of "hhhh" and "hhhhh". Use the print function with the headCount variable to display the number of four and five consecutive head flips.

Comment: I am confused a bit on how headCount is counting both, it seems when I print the results of it nothing comes up as well

Comment: @Alex if consec == 4 or == 5 counts both of them. I tested this code and am having no issues printing the results.

Comment: I'm sorry when I put in the printing, it prints but no results comes up

Comment: @Alex Are you using the same print function you use for "h" and "t"? I edited my post and renamed variables so you can see exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Could you by any chance help me with the code I just edited above as well? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex You set heads = 0 after checking for 4. You should only assign heads after making ALL of your checks. If heads = 0 after checking for 4 you will never find heads == 5.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. You really shouldn't alter the main question so drastically though, it makes answers seem off topic or just wrong. Next time you should make a new question, but before that you should debug and step through your application. I think if you had done that you would have solved the second issue on your own.